# Compare realm objects

Tags: objective-c, realm

Below, `d` and `dictionary` refer to the same realm object, but both `==` and `isEqual:` result in `NO`.  What is the best method for comparing realm objects that do not have primary keys?

```
(lldb) po d
UserDictionary {
    dateImported = 2016-02-12 03:44:53 +0000;
    dirtyProperties = RLMArray <0x7f01a110> (

    );
    var1 = ingles;
    var2 = ;
    var3 = ;
    name = bab.la (popup);
    url = http://en.bab.la/dictionary/%(var1)s-english/%(term)s;
    toLanguage = es;
    fromLanguage = en;
}

(lldb) po dictionary
UserDictionary {
    dateImported = 2016-02-12 03:44:53 +0000;
    dirtyProperties = RLMArray <0x7a1b4d30> (

    );
    var1 = ingles;
    var2 = ;
    var3 = ;
    name = bab.la (popup);
    url = http://en.bab.la/dictionary/%(var1)s-english/%(term)s;
    toLanguage = es;
    fromLanguage = en;
}
```

This must be done somewhere, because I was able to use indexOfObject in RLMResults as a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isEqualToObject:` checks if two object instances refer to the same underlying persisted object.

Answer (score 2):

The default `isEqual:` implementation simply compares the memory address, as `==` does.

You must implement the `-isEqualToUserDictionary:(UserDictionary*)` yourself.
You can also implement the `-isEqual:(id)` method, but you should 
check the type of the object first inside the method.

You shouldn't compare the primary key of the object, but all of its fields instead.

Implementing `-hash` is a nice way to make your objects comparable.